# How to add headers to all routes in flask?

Tags: flask

I want to add header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to all routes in flask. How can I do?

I tried to use `flask_cors.CORS(app)`, but it didn't work.

I am not a native English speaker, so pleace forgive me for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
# import those packages you have already imported
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def index():
    return render_template('sample.html')
```

If not works then do let me know... will figure it out

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it doesn't seem to work... ```import flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials = True)

@app.route("/test")
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def test():
    return flask.render_template("test.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)``` This is my code, and it returned ```HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 285
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.1
Date: Wed, 04 Aug 2021 08:33:06 GMT```headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First import make response:

```
from flask import make_response
```

Then this:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    r = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
    r.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
flask_cors.CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: it the same as I have given, both are correct and working in my case.